# Not able to configure a DeleteView, getting pattern error

Tags: python, django

So I have been trying to configure a DeleteView for my Lecture model. For my Course model, each course has its own slug page and on that page, I have all lectures for that course. Problem is, that when I'm trying to delete a lecture, I get this error:

```html
Reverse for 'lecture_delete' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['courses\\/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\\/delete\\/$']
```

I guess it has something to do with my slug. Traceback: http://dpaste.com/02X45B5

```js
class LectureDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Lecture
    success_url = reverse_lazy('courses/courses.html')


 <ul>
                    {% for c in category.list %}
                        .............
                        <li>{{ c.lecture_title }}</li>
                        <li>{{ c.content }}</li>
                        {% for file in c.files.all %}
                            {% if file.files %}
                                <li><a href='{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ file.files.url }}'>download</a></li>
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                        Hey, are you sure you want to delete {{ c.lecture_title }}?
                        <form action="{% url "courses:lecture_delete" %}" method="post">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <button  type="submit">Yeap, I'm sure.</button>
                        </form>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
```

```css
class Lecture(models.Model):
    LECTURE_CHOICES = (
        ('Courses', 'Courses'),
        ('Seminars', 'Seminars'),
    )
    course = models.ForeignKey('Course', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='', related_name='lectures', )
    lecture_category = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=LECTURE_CHOICES, default='Courses', )
    lecture_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    content = models.TextField(blank=False, default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.lecture_title)


class FileUpload(models.Model):
    files = models.FileField(upload_to='documents', null=True, blank=True)
    lecture = models.ForeignKey('Lecture', related_name='files', on_delete=None, default=None)
```

```html
 path('<slug:slug>/', views.courses, name='courses'),
 path('<slug:slug>/delete/', views.LectureDelete.as_view(), name='lecture_delete'),
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think your problem is with writing your url in template.

```
<a href="{% url 'delview:item-deleteview' object.slug %}">Delete</a>
```

The above code is a valid code for creating delete view. Please note that I have written `object.slug` in the url template tag to provide the slug for Django to create the correct url. I think that is your problem.

Here is the details of the demo project I made to test my DeleteView which works fine.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('item/<slug:slug>/', views.ItemDetail.as_view(), name='item-detailview'),
    path('item/<slug:slug>/delete/', views.ItemDelete.as_view(), name='item-deleteview'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
class ItemDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Item
    template_name = 'delview/detail.html'


class ItemDelete(generic.DeleteView):
    model = Item
    success_url = '/admin/'
```

I used `/admin/` as my success url for no reason.

**detail.html**

```
{{ object.name }} <br/>

{{ object.slug }} <br/>

<a href="{% url 'delview:item-deleteview' object.slug %}">Delete</a>
```

Please take a look at the url I created above. If someone click this link he will be taken to the delete view. I have removed the `object.slug` variable and successfully recreated your error message. So I think you can find your solution over here.

**item_confirm_delete.html**

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    Are you sure you want to delete?
    <input type="submit" value="Confirm"/>
</form>
```

Please note that this is the confirmation delete page and I did not provide any action attribute to the form element.

Please provide feedback of the output you get on comment section below.

Comment: Well my slug would be Course.slug but that's not helping. I get same output.

Comment: Update: Form action I changed it to: <form action="{% url "courses:lecture_delete" c.id %}" method="post"> and now I get: 'LectureDelete' object has no attribute '_meta'

Comment: I just created a DeleteView without the `slug_field` attribute. There is something else wrong. When you click on the link to delete, does it take you to the confirmation page? Or is the error occurring before going to the confirmation page?

Comment: @DannM I think I solved your problem. Please rewrite your url in template file with the slug variable and it will work.

Comment: <form action="{% url "courses:lecture_delete" c.slug %}" method="post"> I wrote it like this. Same output as first time.

Comment: I am not talking about the action attribute. In fact I didn't set the action attribute at all. I am talking about the link for your deleteview. I will add the codes I used to create the DeleteView for my demo project. Maybe that will help.

Comment: Well, if I put no action attribute, page will show and when I click on button, nothing will happen.

Comment: @DannM Please recheck the answer. I have provided a detailed code base for a successful `DeleteView` which is working for me.

Comment: item_confirm_delete.html where does this file get accessed ?

Comment: This file is in the same folder as `detail.html`. It can be anywhere as long as you tell your view where it is. For me it is in the `templates/<app_name>/item_confirm_delete.html`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165775/discussion-between-dann-m-and-minigunnr).

Comment: Still not working. Please accept my chat invitation.

Comment: I will once I go home brother. Will take a couple of hours.

Comment: By doing exactly as above I get this: http://dpaste.com/1K1T8N8 and then if I change from c.slug to c.id or c.pk the page will show and if I press delete I will get again an error like slug field cannot be resolved. In both cases, there is something about the slug.

Comment: Yes. Thanks anyway.